# Azure Synapse and Jira Rest Api Error 21155

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, jira-rest-api

I am trying to call the Rest Api from Jira via the REST Connector of Synapse.
I always get the error 21155.
Error occured when deserializing source JSON file.
Check if data is in valid JSON.
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value <Path", line 0, position 0.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

I checked in postmen and there it worked and the result is a valid json.

Comment: Can you share rest Api or its Output to verify and detect the problem

Comment: @PratikLad the output is: ErrorCode=JsonInvalidDataFormat,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error occurred when deserializing source JSON file ''. Check if the data is in valid JSON object format.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException,Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.,Source=Newtonsoft.Json,'"

Comment: May be your data format is invalid JSON format, ADF can't help you handle the illegal deserialization. According to the connector [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-jira?tabs=data-factory),ADF supports JIRA connector.Maybe you could try to have a try on that.

Comment: I solved this isseu by using the http connector

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your scenario in my environment like I am also getting output in postman but facing error in ADF as below:

- Getting output in postman
  [image]
- Facing similar error in ADF
  [image]

**I believe the error information implies that the source data's non-standard JSON format prevents ADF from deserializing it. JSON that isn't legal cannot be copied using ADF.** Because when I tried with another Api with Correct Json format output, I am able to see the preview the data, as below:

[image]

The connection [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-jira?tabs=data-factory) states that ADF supports the JIRA connector. Perhaps you could give that a go.

Comment: I fiexed it with using the http connnector!